# Finding the potential difference between a and b

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I'm trying to find the potential difference between point a and b

[image]

And I solved the first part, i.e $V(a)$, but I don't really get how the to set the boundaries for $V(b)$, how are they exactly the same as $V(a)$?
I thought that the lower bound should not be $0$ since the shortest distance is the radius of the top?